# How to encrypt and decrypt a sqlite3 database in Java?

Tags: java, string, sqlite, encryption

First of all I need to encrypt my sqlite3 database, because there are very sensitive data.
Then I would only need to decrypt my database when I need it. How could I do?
I am using the sqlite3-jdbc-3.30.1 and DB Browser for Sqlite.
My databases contains lots of strings. My data is like:

ID , lemma , definition

1   , Hello , an expression of greeting

```
Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\sqlite databases\\library.db"); 
     
    }
    catch(SQLException exc) {}
```

Comment: How do you access the DB? Through JPA-Entities? Or plain JDBC? Or what?

Comment: simple JDBC, I'm using sqlite3 jdbc

Comment: Unless the sqlite API does support generic encryption, you have to do it 'manually' on each read/write operation using the well established java crypto API. I suggest AES256 algorithm.

Comment: I think you can't encrypt directly a db file with java crypto API

Comment: Not the DB as a whole, but each single string which you write into or read from a field.

Comment: This process would be simple but too long for the amount of data I have. It took me 1 minute to encrypt all my data!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220704/discussion-between-krishna-pilato-and-heri).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use SqlCipher this is the Link:

https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/

Answer (score 1):

try this one

http://sqlite-crypt.com/

it will encrypt database data

Comment: My question was another